# How to manipulate certain class inside in a parent tag, getting the ID in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want manipulate a certain class, selecting a ID like a parent, this way a want manipulate the class without define a ID in each class. In this example I want manipulate the class 3, but only the class inside on the div with ID b.

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="1">
    <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
    <div class="4">
</div>
<div id="b">
    <div class="1">
    <div class="2">
    <div class="3"> // This tag is the selected to change
    <div class="4">
</div>
<div id="c">
    <div class="1">
    <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
    <div class="4">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. `$('#b .3')` isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
$("#b .3")
```

or if you wanna specifically get direct child of the parent

```
$("#b > .3")
```

Comment: There is no element with the class `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
var a = document.getElementById('b');
var b = a.getElementsByClassName('3');

alert (b[0].className)
```

SIDENOTE:

Why does it make sense to use javascript over jQuery?

```
CODE                                    ops / sec 
document.getElementById('b');           12,137,211
$('#b');                                350,557
```

Vanilla JS is way faster...

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate selectors from the oldest parent to the deepest child, for your case:

```
$("#b .3)
```

Or easier to understand version:

```
$("#b).find(".3")
```

It first select elements with id `b`, then, from its children, it selects elements with class `3`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID in jQuery you should be able to just use `$('#' + myId + ' .3')` to select the desired element dynamically. In the given example myId would of course be `'b'`. If its always the same element you want to access and all you need is the corresponding selector, then of course the static `$('#b .3')` or `$('#b > .3')` for a direct parent-child relationship suffice.